# ExpressionEngine Expresso Store Super Slow Filtering Categories

Tags: expresso-store

Good Morning,

I'm curious on how we can speed up the search results.  This website is very slow on the filtering of the category results, but the individual entry works great.

Any thoughts on what would be slowing the results?

Cache
http://www.heartlandclassics.com/breeds-available-now/section/category/soft-coated-wheaten-terrier

Without Cache
http://www.heartlandclassics.com/breeds-available-now/section-ee-no-cache/category/soft-coated-wheaten-terrier

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="store" limit="6" dynamic="yes" paginate="both"}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" form_class="form-horizontal"}
        {if total_stock > 0} 
              <input type="text" value="1" size="3" name="item_qty" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;">
                {modifiers}
                    <select name="{modifier_input_name}" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;">
                    {modifier_options}
                          <option value="{option_id}" title="{if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}" {if option_first} selected {/if}>
                          {option_name}
                          {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}
                          </option>
                    {/modifier_options}
                    </select>
                {/modifiers}
                    <div class="col-md-4 nopaddingnomargin shop-base">

                {exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}         
                        <div class="image" style="background-image: url('{image:url:large}');"></div>
                {/exp:channel_images:images}

                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>{title}</h3>
                  <p>{price}</p>              
                            <p class="relatedProduct">
                  <a href="{path="breeds-available-now/overview/category/"}{categories show_group="1"}/{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}">
                  [ Read More ]
                  </a>  

                  <input id="related-item-{entry_id}" type="submit" style="display:none;" name="submit" value="1">
                  <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}">    
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#related-item-{entry_id}').click();">
                  [ Add to Cart ]
                  </a>
                  </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


              {paginate}
              <div class="row centerTxt">
                {pagination_links}
                  <ul class="pagination">
                    {first_page}
                      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
                    {/first_page}

                    {previous_page}
                      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                    {/previous_page}

                    {page}
                      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
                    {/page}

                    {next_page}
                      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
                    {/next_page}

                    {last_page}
                      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
                    {/last_page}
                  </ul>
                {/pagination_links}
              </div>  
              {/paginate}


        {/if}
    {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues ended up being the amount of "modifiers" that the client has in their entries.  They had a dropdown select menu that allowed members to select an airport and then confirm a secondary airport for shipping (785 entries per modifier).  The system them had to filter through them all each time... millions of references which caused the system to have memory issues.

Removing that modifier across the board allowed the site to function as normal.